# Does gas price vary when the amount differ?

Tags: gas

If I send 10 ether to someone do I have to pay more gas when I send 1 ether?

What about custom tokens?

Do I have to pay more gas to send more amount of the erc20 tokens that I created personally?

To sum up, does gas price differ according to the amount of tokens being sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, no, it costs the same. But it may differ if there is some special logic when transferring the tokens.

In the case of Ethers, it will always be the same if the receiver is an EOA (Externally Owned Account, a wallet), since there can't be any logic at the receiving end. If the receiver is a contract, it may start some special processing which may run different parts of the code depending on the amount of Ether sent. In that case the gas cost is different.

In the case of tokens, it doesn't matter who the receiver is, since there is always code which is executed. So there may always be special processing depending on the transferred amount.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
So, you mean to say that amount of gas consumed does not matter according to the tokens being sent. But might need to pay more gas when there's a logic in the contract according to the amount of tokens being sent. Did I understand well?

Comment: The required gas amount may change in both cases (tokens and Ethers), if there is some special logic in a contract which handles (or receives the transfer. But typically the send amount does not influence the gas cost.